# np.insert() into an empty ndarray

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

This is what I wrote:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[]])

np.insert(a, 0, 1, axis=1)
```

My code just ignores the insert line for some reason. I even tried
np.put_along_axis() but it's showing an error

I just want to insert or append or put a number into an ndarray.
This forces me to turn it into a normal list, append and turn it back.
Please help

Comment: running your example I get `array([[1.]])` which means `1` was correctly inserted in `a` at position `0`. Why isn't this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

> Returns: out: ndarray

> A copy of arr with values inserted. Note that insert does not occur in-place: a new array is returned. If axis is None, out is a flattened array.

So I think all that's missing here is to assign the modified array back to `a`:

```
a = np.insert(a, 0, 1, axis=1)
```